# vim :remove numbers in selection

Tags: regex, vim, replace

I want to delete the numbers in the following selection in vim, then remove newlines to change this:

```
    global cR, 
cG , 3
cY , 4
cB , 5
cPink , 14
cC , 7
clC , 15
clY , 12
cGray , 9
clGray , 249
clG , 11
cllC , 82
cO , 209
```

to

```
 global cR,cG,...
```

I tried

```
'<,'>%s/\d\+//g
```

But it throws: `E488 trailing characters`

Comment: Don't use `%`. You can only have one range specifier. `%` means all lines in the file. `'<,'>` means selected lines.

Comment: thanks, that solved the problem